# Extract csv data from column x to column y, and from row 1 to row 2 c++

Tags: c++, split, export-to-csv, save-as

I have a .csv file, let's say, 1000 rows and 1200 columns.

How to extract the data from desired column, *let's say 67*, to another column, *let's say 890*.
And at the same time from a row, *let's say 9*, to another row, *let's say 789*, then export the data as new csv file with C++?

I am still beginner but familiar with for or while loop, and I can read a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    ifstream csvFile;

    csvFile.open("../example.csv"); 

    if (csvFile.is_open())
        {

    string line;

    while(getline(csvFile, line))
    {

    //what to do here

    }
        }

    else {

    cout << "Sorry, the file could not be openend." <<endl;

    return -1;

    }

    csvFile.close();

    return 0;

    }
```

**Edit**
for example source csv file:

```
a,1,11,111
b,2,22,222
c,3,33,333
d,4,44,444
```

let say we want only from column 2 to column 3 and from row 2 to 3, then the result is a new csv file like this:

```
2,22
3,33
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main question is hiw to catch the data/variable from tbe given column/ raw: 
1. need to define the "range" and it

2 take the data with "value2()"

Regarding the look, it just cannot be "at the same time": you have to decide the program goal. thanks!

I am sorry but not quite used with this code inserting, so I put an image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqWQm.jpg)

Comment: The goal is to pick a defined range from the total range of the csv source file then write these data to a new csv file

Comment: Or split the whole csv file at defined number of columns only, then writing these generated files to csv files, then one can do normal splitting at row with help of many online service websites

Comment: I am thinking about two nested for loop, the outer loop takes the horizontal range and the inner loop takes the vertical range

Comment: very well with two bested loops. Beside the range as you got for the whole fike, Consider one more range, necessary to handle each cell value

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to doing this. The first that comes to mind is reading your `.csv` file into a vector of `vector<string>` so that each row/column value is stored in a 2D array like vector container of vectors. (e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<string>> array;`). That allows you to easily parse your `.csv` file using `getline` and a `stringstream` on the line read (delimited on `','`).

You could then write an extract function, that takes a reference to your stored csv values and iterates over the vectors using a range-based iterator for both the individual vectors and strings. At that point it is just a matter of keeping a row-index and column-index and outputting all values for row between your desired range and column within your desired range. A simple function would look similar to:

```
 void extract (vector<vector<string>>const & array, size_t r1, size_t c1,
                size_t r2, size_t c2)
{
    size_t ridx = 0;                    /* row index */
    for (auto& row : array) {           /* range based row iterator */
        size_t cidx = 0;                /* column index */
        if (r1 <= ridx && ridx <= r2) { /* if in row range */
            for (auto& col : row) {     /* range based col iterator */
                if (c1 <= cidx && cidx <= c2) { /* if in col range */
                    if (cidx > c1)      /* if greater than 1st */
                        cout << ",";    /* output separator */
                    cout << col;        /* output value */
                }
                cidx++;                 /* increment col index */
            }
            cout << "\n";               /* output newline */
        }
        ridx++;                         /* increment row index */
        if (ridx > r2)                  /* break if row > r2 */
            break;
    }
}
```

You could have it create a secondary vector of strings for return for further processing or you could simply output the values (or write to another file) as is done above.

Putting the pieces together in a short example that reads your csv file an outputs between row 1, col 1 and row 2 and col 2 as you show in your question, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::vector;

void extract (vector<vector<string>>const & array, size_t r1, size_t c1,
                size_t r2, size_t c2)
{
    size_t ridx = 0;                    /* row index */
    for (auto& row : array) {           /* range based row iterator */
        size_t cidx = 0;                /* column index */
        if (r1 <= ridx && ridx <= r2) { /* if in row range */
            for (auto& col : row) {     /* range based col iterator */
                if (c1 <= cidx && cidx <= c2) { /* if in col range */
                    if (cidx > c1)      /* if greater than 1st */
                        cout << ",";    /* output separator */
                    cout << col;        /* output value */
                }
                cidx++;                 /* increment col index */
            }
            cout << "\n";               /* output newline */
        }
        ridx++;                         /* increment row index */
        if (ridx > r2)                  /* break if row > r2 */
            break;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    string line;
    vector<vector<string>> array;

    if (argc < 2) {
        cerr << "error: insufficient input.\n"
                "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }

    ifstream f (argv[1]);   /* open file */
    if (!f.is_open()) {
        perror (("error while opening file " + string(argv[1])).c_str());
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline (f, line)) {         /* read each line */
        string val;                     /* string to hold value */
        vector<string> row;             /* vector for row of values */
        stringstream s (line);          /* stringstream to parse csv */
        while (getline (s, val, ','))   /* for each value */
            row.push_back (val);        /* add to row */
        array.push_back (row);          /* add row to array */
    }
    f.close();

    cout << "complete array\n\n";           
    for (auto& row : array) {           /* iterate over rows */
        for (auto& val : row)           /* iterate over vals */
            cout << val << "  ";        /* output value      */
        cout << "\n";                   /* tidy up with '\n' */
    }

    cout << "\nextracted array\n\n";
    extract (array, 1, 1, 2, 2);        /* extract from 1,1 to 2,2 */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the range-based loop are a C++11 feature, so add `-std=c++11` to your compile string)

You do not have to read your entire file into storage. You can just as easily keep the row and column count during the initial read of lines, and the parsing of columns with `stringstream` and only fill `array` with the values you wish to output, or just output the values at that time, but by encapsulate the `extract` routine in a function, you can operate on as many different ranges of your csv file as you like. It's entirely up to you. The full read just gives you the option of outputting as many different parts of your file as you want without having to perform I/O more than once on the original file.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/iostream_sstream_csv dat/extract.csv
complete array

a  1  11  111
b  2  22  222
c  3  33  333
d  4  44  444

extracted array

2,22
3,33
```

There are probably more C++ ways of bracketing the wanted row and column indexes rather than keeping a simple row-index and column-index, but that works every time. You may look into `distance()` or subtracting the current iterator from your vector`.begin()`, but there are limitations to which iterators that applies to. The good old indexes don't care.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.